How can I ignore a specific value of a property?
I'm trying to figure out how I can ignore a specific value of a property using Mixin.
For example, there is a class:
class MyClass {

  String name;   
}

I want to use a MixIn to ignore names with a value set to "ignoreThis" or "ignoreThat". Is there a way to ignore these specific values?
interface MixIn {

  @JsonIgnore
  String getName();   
}


By "ignore" do you mean replace with null?

Is there a specific reason you want to do that?

I'm not sure this will work but you can give try:
Step 1: You need to create Custom Serializer and in that you need to Serialize only if the value is not ignored
eg: if (!"ignoreThis".equals(value) && !"ignoreThat".equals(value)) {

// code
}
Step 2: You can replace add this snippet to your interface  :
@JsonSerialize(using = NameSerializer.class) String getName();
then Apply the mixin to MyClass
then Test serialization
May be it will work
